# Can i monitor the remote access under windows

Tags: c#, remote-desktop

There are two machine A and B.
Install a software or a service in the machine B.
Now,machine A through the remoting access the machine B.
how to monitor this action.

Comment: do you mean remote desktop connection?

Comment: are do you want to restrict access to machine B?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if your application is winforms application you can use System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession. if this returns true your user connected through remote desktop connection.

Answer (score 1):

you can try a Windows Remote Desktop Connection (Some Video tutorials are [here](http://windows.microsoft.com/is-IS/windows7/Connect-to-another-computer-using-Remote-Desktop-Connection))

**OR**

try [LogMeIn](https://secure.logmein.com/)

Comment: ? thank you for your answer.but i means that i want to monitor the remote access action on machine B by the C#.

Comment: what you want is to create an application that can monitor the remote access action on machine B?